# Changes in Equinox Framework Config

Tags: osgi, equinox

Using version 3.7 of equinox I can set : 
    Constants.FRAMEWORK_STORAGE_CLEAN, "true" and
    "osgi.console", consolePortasString()

With equinox version 3.9 setting FRAMEWORK_STORAGE_CLEAN to "true" does not work but setting to "onFirstInit" does.

Has the "true"setting been intentionally dropped from equinox?

Also the console port setting does not work in 3.9.

What is the suggested/intended method for setting these values in 3.9?